# Moving from HDD to SSD with windows in SSD

Tags: hard-drive, 17.10

I have 2 HDDs for data and 1 SSD for operating systems. I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on one of the HDDs and now I want to move it to the SSD. My windows 10 is on /dev/sda4 which the SSD I want to make a 40 GB 5th partition and copy the ubuntu to it. My Ubuntu currently in /dev/sdc3.

Comment: You should do a new install. If not willing to wait until 18.04 is released at end of April you can still install it, but it may have issues. But you have old install to fall back to. UEFI or BIOS installs? After your new install, just restore your normal backup of /home, your exported list of apps & other things you may include in your backup. Also good way to test that your back up procedure includes everything you really need to totally restore system.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to reinstall everything , because you will experience problems , maybe the windows is on IDE and not AHCI , so you will need to format the windows .. see , backup the really necessary things on your windows and move it to the new SSD